# Questions about derivation of Fano resonance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions, resonance

In Fano's original paper about Fano resonance [https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.124.1866], starting from equation (3b)

$$V_{E'}a+E'b_{E'}=Eb_{E'}\tag{3b}$$

one gets an expression for $b_{E'}$

$$b_{E'}=\left[\frac{1}{E-E'}+z(E)\delta(E-E')\right]V_{E'}a\tag{4}$$

question (1): where does the second part $z(E)\delta(E-E')$ come from?

continuing from here, Fano says if the continuum states $\psi_{E'}$ has asymptotic behavior $\propto \sin[k(E')r+\delta]$, the integral over the first term on the right side of (4) multiplied by $\sin[k(E')r+\delta]$ yields, for large $r$, $-\pi \cos[k(E)r+\delta]V_{E}a$.

The integration is
$$\int \frac{1}{E-E'}\sin[k(E')r+\delta]V_{E'}a \ dE',$$
I integrate over the this contour

[image]

and what I get is $2\pi i \sin[k(E)r+\delta]V_{E}a$.

question (2) how does one get the result $-\pi \cos[k(E)r+\delta]V_{E}a$?

Comment: The paper explicitly explains how to understand the equations and it even gives a reference.

Comment: the reference is in German.. and I think it doesn't resolve question 2

Comment: Isn't the reference Dirac's book (IIRC)? Anyway, yes, it does not resolve the second question, but definitely answers the first.